# Why there is difference in sizes between normal object & pointer object of same class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, sizeof

Greetings programming enthusiasts..
While learning objects in C++ i came across one doubt about sizes of objects as follows..

1.Fisrt case

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sample
{
    private:
        double i;
        int aa;

    public:
        sample()
        {

        }                   
};//end class sample

int main()
{       
    sample arr;
    cout<<sizeof(arr)<<endl;
}//end main
```

When i ran this code compiler gives output `16`.

2.Second case

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class sample
{
    private:
        double i;
        int aa;

    public:
            sample()
            {

            }                   
};//end class sample

int main()
{       
    sample *arr;
    cout<<sizeof(arr)<<endl;
}//end main
```

Now this time compiler gave me output `4`.

My question is why is there diffrence is output when object is changed from "sample arr" to "sample *arr". ??

Comment: you have two different types. Why should their size be the same?!

Comment: @artm `sizeof(pointer) = sizeof(int)` – no.

Comment: @artm: The two are not related. A pointer needs to be big enough to hold any address in memory, and an `int` needs to be big enough to hold values in the range [-32767, 32767] (16 bits). Nowadays, on 64 bit systems, pointers are 64 bits, and ints are usually 32 bits (they don't have to be). Although people still often build for 32 bit systems, and there, it is often the case that they are both 32 bits.

Comment: @artm Maybe you should remove your confusing comment? OP is already confused enough.

Answer (score 2):

in your second example, `sizeof` is giving you the size of a pointer, which is 4 bytes (on a 32-bit machine). in your first example, `sizeof` is giving you the size of your object, which happens to be 16 bytes (after padding i believe ...)

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are checking the size of the `sample` class - i.e., the size it takes to store an `int` and `double`, plus some padding, probably.

The second example is the size of a pointer - the size it takes to represent a memory address. This should be the same for any datatype, regardless of its size.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer only describes where in memory your object can be found, so the `sizeof` of your pointer will not necessarily be the same `sizeof` your object.

As a real-world example, a piece of paper might tell you where someone's house is, but that piece of paper is nowhere near the size of the house itself! The two pieces of information/data are different things.

Try this as an illuminating example; create an object, create a pointer to it, and take the `sizeof` your pointer, as well as the `sizeof` your object. Then also take the `sizeof` the **dereferenced** pointer. See what you find [: